# Value getting reinitialised out of closure

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, asynchronous

I made an array of objects playerArray to store the data of the player, then i call firebase database via ref. In the closure i do get the value from firebase and assign it to the property .name but out of the closure the value gets reinitialised to the initial value.

```
var playerArray:[model] = [model]()

let ref = Database.database().reference().child("Players").child("Ronaldo")


func read(){

    ref.observe(.value) { (snap) in
        var val = snap.value as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
        let name = val["Name"] as! String
        let Model = model()
        Model.name = name
        self.playerArray.append(Model)
        print(snap)
    }

} 
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    read()
    table.delegate = self
    table.dataSource = self
    table.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to the question - Use _lowerCamelCase_ for variable names and _UpperCamelCase_ for type names.

Comment: Use `single observer` instead of `observe`, Reload your table in closure because you will not get data where you're reloading the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you don't reload the table view after the data has been retrieved in `read` asynchronously. You simply need to call `reloadData` from inside the completion handler of `observe`.

```
ref.observe(.value) { (snap) in
    var val = snap.value as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
    let name = val["Name"] as! String
    let Model = model()
    Model.name = name
    self.playerArray.append(Model)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.table.reloadData()
    }
}
```

There's also no need to call `reloadData` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: in order to check wether the object Model ids being appended to the playerArrray, I printed playerArray[0] in viewdidLoad() after calling the function and the app crashes

Comment: @Tushar it seems like you misunderstand how async methods work. By the time `viewDidLoad` finishes execution synchronously, `read` is still being executed asynchronously and hence `playerArray` is empty, so when you try to access its element at index 0, you'll get an index out of bounds error. The value is only added to the array in the completion handler of `observe`, so you cannot access it from outside the completion handler.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 1):

You should reload your table after the change of the parameter. in viewDidLoad() it just happens once.

Answer (score 0):

After appending the `playerArray` in the closure body, you should refresh tableview

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    table.delegate = self
    table.dataSource = self
    read()
}


func read(){

    ref.observe(.value) { (snap) in
        var val = snap.value as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
        let name = val["Name"] as! String
        let Model = model()
        Model.name = name
        self.playerArray.append(Model)
        print(snap)
        self.table.reloadData()

    }

}
```